# Hide/Show worksheet based on cell value

Tags: vba, loops, hide, show

I'm currently working on a Macro that looks at specific cell values in a master worksheet and determines whether certain worksheets within the workbook should be hidden or shown. (for example, if cell E13 of master worksheet is 0 then worksheet "bank" should be hidden). The workbook has multiple cells it needs to evaluate, so I tried to use a For Next loop to achieve this but every time I get to the loop the error message Object doesn't support this property or method comes up. I am unsure as to why this is happening?

```
  Sub Calculate_Sheet()
If Not ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit Sub
Dim ws() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim index As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").xlEnd(Up).Row

For i = 13 To FinalRow
index = i - 13
ReDim ws(0 To index)
ws(index) = Cells(i, "A").Value
If Cells(i, "E").Value = 0 And Cells(i, "F").Value = 0 Then
Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = xlHidden
Else
Worksheets(ws(index)).Visible = xlVisible
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry code line number 9 is suppose to read index = i - 13

Comment: In your first loop You are trying to `ReDim ws(1 to 0)`, because `index = 13-13=0`

Comment: correct FinalRow line to FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row